# Add stylesheets and js to template files when shortcode is used

Tags: plugins, scripts, css

After looking for days throught the net and no avail - i'd like to ask all of you guys.

PROBLEM: i need to add custom code to the head of the file as part of shortcode use for my plugin. The same files and code insert fine in the admin page (backend) but fail to load in the template file.

The files are inserted in the admin head with add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'add_swm_scripts'); & add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_swm_styles'); calls pointing to functions that use wp_enqueue_script() and wp_register_style() / wp_enqueue_style()
This does fine - however - when i try to get the same files registered in the function of the shortcode (for use in the template), nothing workds.

I checked that the shortcode is read and it's according function is fired, but neither add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'swm_scripts' ); , add_action('init', 'register_swm_scripts'); nor add_action('wp_head', 'print_swm_scripts'); will work.
I've tried more than this not don't find a working solution. If somebody knows a valid trick - i more than appreciate some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Herbie

Comment: The question is sort of answered.
add_action calls are not possible from within the shortcode handler. Thanks helgatheviking

Answer (score 2):

put wp_enqueue_script() in your shortcode handler.

```
add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'my_shortcode_handler');

function my_shortcode_handler($atts) {
  wp_enqueue_script('my-script', plugins_url('my-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

  // actual shortcode handling here
  return "bacon flavored shortcode here";
}
```

this definitely loads the my-script.js file for me.  it gets loaded in the footer though.  i don't think there is a way for it to load conditionally in the header as it won't have gotten to the post content to know whether the shortcode is used or not.

check this:
http://scribu.net/wordpress/conditional-script-loading-revisited.html

Comment: i do and still nothing.
the plugin main page holds the add_shortcode and refers to a function in my functions file. it gets called and also errors when messed with but the add_action calls do nothing...

Comment: It is helpful to copy relevant example code into the WPSE answer, in case the linked resource goes away in the future.

Comment: could it be that the theme supresses the calls?

Comment: I tried the method from the link you posted:

add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'my_shortcode_handler');
 
function my_shortcode_handler($atts) {
 wp_enqueue_script('my-script', plugins_url('my-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
 
 // actual shortcode handling here
}

but it won't do anything...

In the same article it is mentioned that calls from within the body won't work - but the shortcode is only used in posts - that seems like a contradiction.

Comment: ChipBennett you're right. done. but it'd be a sad day for WP if scribu's site goes away!  herbie - there is no add_action call inside your shortcode.  i just tested and the code in my answer works. i also verified that you don't even need to specific that last true parameter (which means load in footer) as it will automatically be added in the footer

Comment: ok. you have been faster helgatheviking. No add_action calls inside the shortcode handler - Brings me to the next problem - i need data contained in the shortcode to query my db and generate additional markup code - But it does not matter how i define it the variable ends up with the default specified in the shortcode handler. Any idea how i can pre-check if a shortcode is contained in the page and what values are asigned to it?

Comment: that is kind of a different animal altogether.  probably warrants a new question.  though i think if you need the info in the shortcode for markup/query purposes you probably should be using post meta?

Comment: Haha. Yeah i know - different animal. But it resulted from the 'answer' you gave me. No add_action calls in the shortcode handler forces me to to a workarround ;-)
Thx again!

Comment: welcome. if my answer solved this particular question could you mark it resolved?  also, if you create a new q and explain more about what you are doing you might get an answer for that too.

Comment: will do when i can - there's a timelimit for new users